# d3 Automation Testing

Tags: angularjs, selenium, d3.js, selenium-ide

I need to test some d3 based Angular components and had thought to use Selenium IDE or Kantu, but it seems that these tools cannot record interactions with SVG elements. Are there any tools that would allow me test in this way? Or will I need to rethink the problem and use a different type of testing?

Comment: I don't think using record/replay way to auto D3 is a good option. because there are many elements inside an SVG, even the SVG represents a small chat, and most elements in SVG will have same class, which will give huge challenge to write locator to find element.  Additionally, a small change on chat maybe need internal elements huge  change support.  I very doubt the script generated by Selenium IDE can work stable after record, especially SVG chat is dynamical when chat data changed in most time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool specifically made for UI testing of **angular.js** pages. It's called [protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) . In this, test scripts have to be written in Javascript. Protractor is for end-to-end testing.

If you are going to do unit testing , then the gold standard for unit testing angular code is [Karma](https://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-karma.html). Karma was created and is maintained by the core Angular team and provides many utilities that make it easy to test angular apps.

A combination of both protractor and karma can completely cover an angular app functionality.